Can a space with the following properties exist? Any examples?
Can a space with the following properties exist? Any examples?

The number of geodesic paths between any two points is infinite but countable.

The infimum of the geodesic path lengths between any two points is zero.

For any two points there is a maximum finite geodesic path length.

The maximum geodesic path length between two points has properties, similar to the distance in metric space, except it is, oviously not minimal, but maximal geodesic path.


I want to point out that this hypothetical space has properties, similar to a torus, such as Clifford torus, for example, but with minimum and infimum replaced with miximum and supremum and zero with infinity.

Do you have an example of a space with only the first property?

@M.Winter Cliffird torus. Any torus, in fact.

I am not experienced in thinking about geodesic paths, but if between $x$ and $y$ there are two geodesic paths $\gamma$ and $\rho$, then aren't $\gamma(\rho^{-1}\gamma)^n$ also geodesic paths of arbitrarily large length, violating 3?

@M.Winter yes, it violates condition 3, so torus does not satisfy all these conditions. You asked for an example, satisfying only the first property.

But any space satisfying 1 will have two such paths $\gamma$ and $\rho$, so violating 3, or am I getting this wrong?

Thinking a bit more, my second comment is not completely right but further conditions on $\gamma$ and $\rho$ are necessary to ensure that concatenations are geodesic. But it would perhaps be helpful to know a space that satisfies 1 + 3 (and 1 + 2 for that matter).

@M.Winter mmm. Maybe in the space I am searching for length of the path is calculated differently, so the paths produced by your formula are deminishing as n increases.

@M.Winter if it deminishes towards zero, then the condition 2 is automatically satisfied.

Maybe I'm missing some subtle detail, but it seems like property 2 forces the space in question to be a point (regardless of definition of geodesics in general metric space; I suppose they are just locally isometric maps from an interval).

@DenisT Of course, the classic definition of distance between two points would be zero, but we are not talking about distance but about geodesic paths. We can define distance as the biggest geodesic path (rather than smallest as in classic metric spaces).

@Anixx is not the length of every path (including geodesic) between two points in a metric path always not less than the distance between them?

@FedorPetrov classically, distance is defined as the shortest geodesic path. We can define distance as the longest geodesic path. For instance, on a sphere, not shortest but the longest arc connecting two points. Anyway, this question does not mention distance.

@Anixx So why don't you define precisely what you mean by words "metric space" and "geodesic" if you want to use them in non-classic meaning?

@DenisT I've removed "metric" but I am not sure what re-definition a geodesic needs...

@Anixx The one which is present in absence of metric. Are you talking about Busemann spaces, G-spaces, something else?

@DenisT I looked here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busemann_G-space and it seems, the axioms are compatible with the conditions in the question, if under distance we understand the supremum of the length of the geodesic paths.

@DenisT one can think about this aspace as of Euclidean space with "secret geodesics" or "wormholes" between points, which are shorter than conventional geodesics and of countable number for each two points.

A non-empty metric space that satisfies all of these conditions does not exist because condition 2 will force the geodesic metric space to be a point but a metric space with a single point violates condition 1.

Of course, the classic definition of distance between two points would be zero, but we are not talking about distance but about geodesic paths. We can define distance as the biggest geodesic path (rather than smallest as in classic metric spaces).

No, the empty set is an example of such a space.
